# jQuery: Selecting <option> contents with select() rather than change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I am using a plugin for a dropdown that prevents me from using `change()` to find when a dropdown option is selected. How would I do the same with `select()` which it supports?

I currently have:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="images/icons/all.png">All Questions</option>
        <option value="1" id="friends" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends.png">Friends</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="images/icons/friends_of_friends.png">Friends of Friends</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="images/icons/network.png"><?php echo $network; ?></option>
        <option value="4" data-imagesrc="images/icons/location.png"><?php echo $location ?></option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#dropdown').ddslick({
showSelectedHTML: false
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').select(function() {
        var blah = selected dropdown // mock code
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "data.php",
                 data:  {'data': blah},
                 success: function(data) {
                     $('#questions_body').hide().html(data).fadeIn('500');
                 },
                 dataType: "HTML"
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: [`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) is for *text highlighting* events, not for `<select>` menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the select() method has anything to do with this. From the plugin page, though:

*onSelected: Callback function when an option is selected in the drop down. See demo 3 above.*

```
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});
```